# Typhoon Framework: Swift or Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, typhoon

Which language is preferable when developing with Typhoon framework, Swift or Objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer that question directly, however I can give you the information with which to come to your own decision:

Typhoon is a reflective, dynamic dependency injection container and takes advantage of the full Objective-C runtime. Pure Swift classes - ones that do not derive from NSObject - are Objective-C classes "under the hood" but have the following features:

- The Objective-C runtime's reflection methods will not work.
- They use C++ style inline, static or vtable dispatch which essentially prevents dynamic runtime augmentation of classes. Swift is a static language not just in regards to its time system, but also in this regard.

**Answer:**

- You can use whichever language you prefer.

But if you're working in Swift you should be aware:

- Classes being injected by Typhoon should derive from NSObject.

When it comes to Cocoa or Cocoa-touch you'll be working with UIViewControllers, UIViews and so forth, so we don't see this as a problem in the near future. However, eventually we'd like to provide an alternative version of Typhoon that works for "pure" Swift using clojures or perhaps compile-time instrumentation.

Comment: In case anyone interested there has been pure swift version added: https://github.com/appsquickly/TyphoonSwift